# Retina pixel density and CSS overflow-y

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, media-queries, retina

**DISCLAIMER**: This question is long and convoluted, and I'm not sure there's a quick answer, but I'm at the end of mine and my colleagues knowledge and we're coming up empty, plus this is the kind of thing StackOverflow seems to love.

## The Problem

I have a legacy application that is built using jQuery Mobile for the front-end UI. There is an issue only on high-dpi breakpoints where a div that has `overflow-y: auto;` and does not need to overflow (the content does not extend beyond the end of the container) will render as blank.

Viewing the same container on a standard-dpi breakpoint does not produce the same result.

If I change the CSS rule to `overflow-y: visible;` or `overflow-y: hidden;` then the issue does not occur, but then the scrolling does not function correctly in the event that the container **does** overflow.

See screenshots below:

[image: Standard DPI Breakpoint]
*Standard DPI Breakpoint, the content shows up correctly.*

[image: High DPI Breakpoint]
*High-DPI Breakpoint, the content does not show up*

I know that this is a rendering issue (and not a CSS flub) because I can force the screen to redraw by resizing the window and the content shows right back up. So our customers can get around the issue, but it is bothersome.

### Next Steps

I'm wondering if there is a way to force high-dpi screens to render at a standard DPI, because that might be the fastest way to fix this issue. Otherwise, what course could I pursue to get this regression resolved? I might add that this issue only cropped up in the latest versions of Chrome, I think around 39.

Comment: This will be just a quick, intuitive, dirty workaround suggestion: "I know that this is a rendering issue (and not a CSS flub) because I can force the screen to redraw by resizing the window and the content shows right back up." - have you tried playing with triggering "resize" event on window? Like so: `$(window).trigger('resize');`

Comment: Unfortunately, the size actually needs to change, otherwise it doesn't work. I tried that exactly and it doesn't work - I haven't however tried changing it by one pixel. I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: That didn't work but I did find a fix, I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to fix the rendering issue by forcing GPU rendering. Adding the rule `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` to the selector worked!

Answer (score 0):

transform: translate3d(0,0,0) didn't work in our case. Exactly same problem as you described.
However setting overflow: hidden; on the outer enclosing element did solve the problem in our case.

Comment: We tried that, but if the content extended below - we needed to be able to scroll.

Comment: Yes, you can set overflow to scroll on outer element. But introduce another new surrounding element and set that to overflow:hidden. The scroll should work as it is dependent on immediate outer element overflow definition. Rendering will be consistent because the outermost element has overflow: hidden.